# Center of $SU(N)$ group in general Young-tableaux representation

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

Let us consider $ SU(2)$ irrep. with a $1\times k$ Young tableaux. Then the center group of such linear representation depends on the value of $k$ in the following sense. If $k\in$odd, then the center is nontrivial, namely $Z_2$, while the center is trivial when $k\in$even.

I wonder whether it can be generalized to $SU(N)$ irrep. with a general Young tableaux consisting of $b$ blocks. What I can guess or expect is the result should be that the center is $Z_{N/(b,N)}$ where $(b,N)$ is the greatest common divsor of $b$ and $N$. Is this statement correct? If so, how to prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix representing the center generator of $SU(N)$ can be calculated within some (larger) irreducible representation since the matrix is proportional to the identity matrix. More specifically, any Young-tableaux representation with $b$ blocks is contained in the $b$-fold tensor product of fundamental representations, namely 
\begin{eqnarray}
\text{irrep}(b)\in\otimes_1^bN.
\end{eqnarray}
Thus we can calculated the prefactor by the right-hand side: 
\begin{eqnarray}
Z(b)&=&\left[\exp(i2\pi/N)\right]^b\nonumber\\
&=&\exp(i2\pi b/N), 
\end{eqnarray}
which generates $Z_{N/(b,N)}$.